# Apache block access to directory with 404

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404

I was trying to block access to directory but the problem is that use will get 403, The problem is that i dont want the user even know there was a folder so i want him to get 404 instead, The closest thing i found is([Link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory)):

```
<Directory /web/docs>
ErrorDocument 404 default
</Directory>
```

But it didnt worked, If anyone know the right syntax or a way at all of doing so i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

In a .htaccess in your folder

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
```

But with this code, you will no longer be able to access your folder/files.